# IPtables doens't block client to client communication

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iptables, hostapd, ubuntu-22.04

I'm working on a project with my fellow students, and we've discovered a vulnerability in a IP camera. This camera uses port 8554 for the rtsp protocol (it's unauthenticated). I want to block this port so that other people on the network cant access the live camera footage via the RTSP protocol (though it's accessible from the cloud, don't worry about that)

For the proof of concept, I've configured a SBC to function as a router with hostapd, dnsmasq, dhcpcd and iptables installed. I've tried various approaches, but it doens't seem to block the port or even block the client to client communication on the lan. Even the hostapd ap_isolate=1 doesnt work.

Some information:

- wlan0: Access Point
- wlan1: Internet
- All clients need internet

These are the rules i tried:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8554 -d 192.168.0.76 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8554 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 8554 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i $WIFI -o $WIFI -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

and I've tried some additional rules similar to these

And from hostapd config: ap_isolate=1 (did nothing, even after restart)

These are my settings from hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ieee80211n=1
ssid=xxxxxxx
hw_mode=g
channel=10
wmm_enabled=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=xxxxxxxx
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ap_isolate=1
```

Thank you in advanced for your responses